# Azure Notification Hub direct send java

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

According to the rest APIs there is a concept of direct send which takes the pns credentials in the header to send the push notification directly onto the specific device but right now no such method exists in the official version of the Notifications Hub JAVA SDK. In unofficial version of the API, method was there but now it is being removed.

Comment: This isn't a question...

Comment: sorry my bad the question is how i can send the push notification to a device directly using Notification HUb JAVA SDK